# Use Task or Thread when Coding a Remote Desktop Capture App

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.5

Recently I'm coding a remote desktop app.

For the client side, I have a Windows Forms app that have a picturebox control and a button. Internally I have two Listeners, and two TcpClient, one for holding the connection and another for receive the image from the remote computer.

For the server side, who is a console app, I have two TcpClient objects that connects to the remote client. When connection is established the server start taking snapshots of the desktop and sending them to the client. then the client receive the image and shows the image on the picture box control.

To show the image on the picturebox and assuring that it is asynchronously one must use Task or Thread. But in this situation which on is better to use for receive the image and show it on the picturebox control?

Best Regards

**EDIT:**
Complementing my question, which would be best in performance terms and system resource usage terms?

Comment: When you say `Task` are you meaning a task returned from `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` or are you referring to a task returned by a function that has the `async` keyword (`public async Task YourFunc(){...}`)

Comment: Either one is good, that the difference is little among them. but I personally would use Task.Run.

Comment: My point with that question is ***you should not be making threads at all*** (Both `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` both create a new thread), you should be using the async methods like [`ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx) and awaiting for data to arrive.

Comment: In my app I use the Async methods but this question came across me when I saw various example on the web using Threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to use the `Thread` class, it is quite low level and difficult to combine separate asynchronous operations together.

`Task` APIs are much easier to use and combine multiple asynchronous operations together, they also support cancellation and have language support through the `async` and `await` keywords which makes writing asynchronous code much easier, although one still needs to be aware of how it works as there can be a few gotchas. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more details on best practices.

Comment: Interesting, but in terms of performance and system resources tasks continue to be better than Threads?

Comment: yes in terms of memory consumption, for I/O bound work, because windows I/O is asynchronous using tasks uses less threads and therefore less memory as each thread has 1MB of stack.

Comment: In terms of actual time duration `async` requires some thread context switching which delays it slighlty